# Inconsistent User List from Admin SDK

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have been listing users with Directory API, There are some inconsistencies in the number of users listed.

I am able to retrieve the information of a user using

```
admin_service.users().get(userKey = email).execute()
```

but when that user is not present when retrieved from the list API

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,PRIVATE_KEY,SCOPE,prn = "admin@domain.com")

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

admin_service = build("admin", "directory_v1",http = http)
admin_service.users()

user_list = user_service.list(domain="company.com")
listed_users = user_list.execute()

final_user_list = listed_users["users"]
while "nextPageToken" in listed_users.keys():
    user_list = user_service.list(pageToken = listed_users["nextPageToken"])
    listed_users = user_list.execute()
    final_user_list += listed_users["users"]

return final_user_list
```

For example if the List API returns 2000 users, and user john.doe@domain.com is missing from the list.

When querying the details of john.doe@domain.com from API we get a successful result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,PRIVATE_KEY,SCOPE,prn = "admin@domain.com")
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("admin", "directory_v1",http = http)
final_user_list = []

page_token = None
while True:
    users = service.users().list(domain="replace_your_domain_name", pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for entry in users.get("users"):
        user_email = entry.get('primaryEmail')
        final_user_list.append(user_email)
    page_token = users.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if not page_token:
        break
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with Google's APIs not returning all the users rather than an issue with the logic flow.
The flow that I posted has been in production for quite sometime.

Comment: did you set domain parameter in list method [service.users().list(domain="replace_your_domain_name",)]

Comment: Yes, This code has been in production for sometime now

Comment: in your question, the line user_list = user_service.list(), you didn't set domain parameter this causes to get an error from google. Are you getting any error from google?

Comment: No I am not getting an error, In fact it returns a list of users, but the problem is that It is not consistent as I mentioned in the question